# indice do array retornando undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fetch

Estou utilizando um array global para quando iterar determinados objetos dentro de uma função assincrona, os colocar nesse array global, mas ao tentar acessar os indices desse array depois da iteração tenho só o retorno undefined

```js
const listaP = [];
async function PegarPokemon() {
  const pokemons = await (
    await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10")
  ).json();
  return pokemons.results;
}
async function Pokemons_array() {
  const pokemons = await PegarPokemon();

  pokemons.forEach(async (element) => {
    let infoPokemon = await (
      await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${element.name}`)
    ).json();
    listaP.push(infoPokemon);
  });
  console.log(listaP); // array completo
  console.log(listaP[0]); // undefined AQUI QUE ENTRA O PROBLEMA
  return listaP;
}

Pokemons_array();
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você se equivocou.

A lista `listaP` está vazia no momento em que você loga ela. A razão de que você vê ela completa no console, é porque o `console.log` só envia uma referencia da lista para o console, e quando você finalmente decide verificar o que foi logado, um tempo se passou e ela já foi preenchida.

O que está acontecendo é que o método `forEach` recebe uma função de *callback* para ser executada a cada iteração. Se essa função é *async* ou não, o `forEach` não se importa, ele não irá esperar pela resolução da *Promise* para executar a próxima iteração. Ou seja, o `forEach` roda por completo antes mesmo das suas funções *async* terminarem de processar.

Uma saída para isso é evitar *callbacks*. Contanto que o *await* esteja no contexto da sua função principal, você poderá usar o *await* para aguardar a resolução:

```
for (const element of pokemons) {
    const infoPokemon = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${element.name}`).json();
    listaP.push(infoPokemon);
}
```

Mas existe outra forma mais eficiente de fazer isso: você pode criar um *array* de *Promises* e usar a função `Promise.all` para aguardar a resolução de todas as *Promises* ao mesmo tempo, ao invés de aguardar uma de cada vez:

```
await Promise.all(pokemons.map(async element => {
    const infoPokemon = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${element.name}`).json();
    listaP.push(infoPokemon);
}));
```

Comment: muito obrigadooooo